# Vectorizing merge/union of two sorted arrays

Tags: vectorization, sse, avx

I have recently started looking into opportunities to speed up my code by using vector instructions. My code heavily relies on operations with sets - for simplicity let us assume that these are represented as sorted arrays of 16bit unsigned integers. The operations I need to perform are:

1. Intersection (i.e., each element contained in both sets is to be present in the output set)
2. Union (i.e., each element that is contained in at least one of the sets is to be present in the output set exactly once)
3. Merge (works exactly as merge in merge-sort, the output is a sorted "concatenation" of both arrays)

I have found works focusing on vectorizing intersection (e.g., http://www.adms-conf.org/p1-SCHLEGEL.pdf) but I had little luck with finding anything for the other two operations. I am curious, is it possible to speed up also the other two operations by vectorization? (I am targeting CPUs either with AVX or AVX2 instruction sets.)

Comment: What sort of population are your sets, typically ? E.g. a few members, or thousands of members ?

Comment: The typical size of the set is around 10,000 elements - but it may grow larger after multiple union/merge operations are applied.

Comment: OK so might it be worth using an 8kb bitmap representation for each set, rather than an array of 16 bit ints ? That would certainly make the intersection/merge/union operations very straightforward with SIMD.

Comment: @PaulR The 8kb bitmap solution would only work for the intersect and union problems (i.e., no duplicates in the arrays). I don't know if the OP wants to allow duplicates, though ...

Comment: @chtz: yes, OPs requirements are not very clear - we need the "bigger picture" really, but he hasn't been back to comment further,