# Merge sort on simd register

Tags: mergesort, simd, cpu-registers, sorting-network

Can anyone think of a way to perform merge sort on 8 elements of an simd register within 3 steps and 4 comparisons in each step?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why specifically *merge* sort?  See http://olab.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~kamil.rocki/xiaochen_rocki_IA3_SC13.pdf for an AVX512  `_mm512 mask max epi32` an min, with `_mm512 shuff le epi32` to shuffle elements between two registers to build a sorting network.  Without AVX512 masking, other papers have shown using packed min/max to build a comparator, and again using `shufps` to combine elements from 2 registers.

Comment: For example http://delta.cs.cinvestav.mx/~francisco/p348-furtak.pdf from 2007 is an SSE2 version of building a SIMD sorting network for sorting *within* a register or pair of registers, using the same packed min/max and shufps.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336261